# Angular Template: Use variable as object key

Tags: angular, angular-template

In a Typescript file you can do this:

```
const myProperty = 'id';
const queryParams = {[myProperty]: 5};
```

How can this be done in a Angular template? It should be something like this:

```
<div 
[routerLink]="../.." 
[queryParams]="{[myProperty]: 5}">
Navigate to page...
</div>
```

This doesn't work because of the square brackets around `myProperty`. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do in Angular template. Why not just construct the object and declare it in variable in component. Then in HTML, you can refer to that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to implement link-parameters-arrays?

https://angular.io/guide/router#link-parameters-array

```
<a [routerLink]="['/crisis-center', { foo: 'foo' }]">Crisis Center</a>
```